# Regex find many word in the string

Tags: regex, go

I want to get all work in string - that are between the pair of `{word}`

Example:

```
payment://pay?id={appid}&transtoken={transtoken}
```

Result expect:

```
["appid", "transtoken"]
```

With regex partern: `{\w+}`, I only can get `[{appid}, {transtoken}]`.

Please help me with the problem.

Comment: Use `\`{(\w+)}\``

Comment: It's not work, bro @WiktorStribiżew. :(

Comment: It does, see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450851/3832970).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following pattern with [`FindAllStringSubmatch`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllStringSubmatch):

```
{(\w+)}
```

See the Go regexp documentation:

> `FindAllStringSubmatch` is the 'All' version of `FindStringSubmatch`; it returns a slice of all successive matches of the expression, as defined by the 'All' description in the package comment. A return value of nil indicates no match.

and

> `FindStringSubmatch` returns a slice of strings holding the text of the leftmost match of the regular expression in `s` **and the matches, if any, of its subexpressions**, as defined by the 'Submatch' description in the package comment. A return value of nil indicates no match.

See the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/LeQGbV0lLKv):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := `payment://pay?id={appid}&transtoken={transtoken}`
    rex := regexp.MustCompile(`{(\w+)}`)
    results := rex.FindAllStringSubmatch(s,-1)
    for _, value := range results  {
        fmt.Printf("%q\n", value[1])
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"appid"
"transtoken"
```